# drools can't get the data I need for the or condition

Tags: conditional-statements, drools, rules

```
rule "151"
    when
        $master:BusinessMaster()
        $map:HashMap() from $master.indexMap
        $mapads_mst_bas_info:HashMap() from $map.get("ads_mst_bas_info")
        $mapads_mst_order_mutl_stat4:HashMap() from $map.get("ads_mst_order_mutl_stat4")
        $resultMap:HashMap((( $mapads_mst_bas_info.get("mst_integral") >= 500 &&  <= 5000 ) || ( $mapads_mst_order_mutl_stat4.get("current_mon_bad_rate_num") >= 1 &&  <= 2 )) && ($mapads_mst_bas_info.get("remain_amount")>=5000)) from $master.indexMap
    then
        $master.getMasterLabel().add("151");
        insert($master);
end
```

This rule is the same as the following rule:

```
rule "151"
    when
        $master:BusinessMaster()
        $map:HashMap() from $master.indexMap
        $mapads_mst_bas_info:HashMap() from $map.get("ads_mst_bas_info")
        $mapads_mst_order_mutl_stat4:HashMap() from $map.get("ads_mst_order_mutl_stat4")
        $resultMap:HashMap((( $mapads_mst_bas_info.get("mst_integral") >= 500 &&  <= 5000 ) || $mapads_mst_order_mutl_stat4.get("current_mon_bad_rate_num") >= 1 && $mapads_mst_order_mutl_stat4.get("current_mon_bad_rate_num") <= 2 ) && ($mapads_mst_bas_info.get("remain_amount")>=5000)) from $master.indexMap
    then
        $master.getMasterLabel().add("151");
        insert($master);
end
```

Both rules have the same result

Answer (score 0):

Your rules *are* identical. The only difference is a set of parentheses `( )` that don't actually matter because of order of operations / operator precedence rules.